# Sending email with laravel, but doesn't recognize variable

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-4, undefined

I'm trying to send an email through Laravel, but I'm getting this error:

> Undefined variable: contactEmail

Even though it got defined above it. What is going wrong here?

**Controller**

```
$contactName = Input::get('name');
$contactEmail = Input::get('email');
$contactMessage = Input::get('message');

$data = array('name'=>$contactName, 'email'=>$contactEmail, 'message'=>$contactMessage);
Mail::send('template.mail', $data, function($message)
{   
    $message->from($contactEmail, $contactName);
    $message->to('info@aallouch.com', 'myName')->subject('Mail via aallouch.com');
});
```

**EDIT:**

**template.mail**

```
Name: {{$name}}
Email: {{$email}}
Message:{{$message}}
```

Comment: Please show us your template.mail. You might have more than one problem.

Comment: Did an other Edit, fixed some of it. The template.mail is in the edit (that's all I have in that file). But I'm still getting `Undefined variable: contactEmail` You can also test it out at www.aallouch.com/contact then fill in the form and you'll see the error messages

Comment: Change your template to `this is just a test` and try to send your e-mail. First I think you might have a stmp problem. To be clearer, remove all blade from it.

Comment: Changed it. But same error contactEmail not defined even though it is defined just above it. It's in the controller

Comment: Ok, got it, just edited my message. You have to pass them using `use ($contactEmail, $contactName)`.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

As your $data variable is defined as:

```
$data = array(
    'name'=>$contactName, 
    'email'=>$contactEmail, 
    'message'=>$contactMessage
);
```

You won't have a $data available in your view, but you can use directly:

```
{{ $name }}
{{ $email }}
{{ $message }}
```

EDIT:

And your controller should have:

```
    $contactName = Input::get('name');
    $contactEmail = Input::get('email');
    $contactMessage = Input::get('message');

    $data = array('name'=>$contactName, 'email'=>$contactEmail, 'message'=>$contactMessage);
    Mail::send('template.mail', $data, function($message) use ($contactEmail, $contactName)
    {   
        $message->from($contactEmail, $contactName);
        $message->to('info@aallouch.com', 'myName')->subject('Mail via aallouch.com');
    });
```

You must pass your variables to the closure using

```
use ($contactEmail, $contactName)
```

As shown above.

Comment: Okay that is working, but in the email I'm having `Name: {{$name}} Email: {{$email}} Message:{{$message}}` the variables aren't being printed

Comment: Is your template named .blade.php?

Comment: No, but just did it and getting error: `Object of class Illuminate\Mail\Message could not be converted to string`

Comment: You might need to change your `$message` to something like `$messageBody`. Looks like `function($message)` is being passed to your view in place of your `$message`.

Comment: It was super helpful that you showed  "pass your variables to the closure using `use ($contactEmail, $contactName)`".  I had never known how to pass variables to a closure.  Thanks!

Comment: Old post. But solved my problem. I wasn't aware of "Closures" in PHP. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I have got this error and I have solved it. I have replace `$message` keyword with `$comment` from $data.

Example below :

```
$data = array('name' => 'vikas', 'message' => 'test message');
```

view

```
{{ $name }}
{{ $message }}
```

It's getting error

```
$data = array('name' => 'vikas', 'comment' => 'test message');

{{ $name }}
{{ $comment }}
```

Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [source code](https://github.com/illuminate/mail/blob/master/Mailer.php#L226) you'll see this line:

```
 $data['message'] = $message = $this->createMessage();
```

So your `message` field is overwritten by that line. Use other name for the field like `text` or `comment`.

Answer (score 0):

I came here to say that if you get this issue in Laravel 5.* or 6.*, make sure that you have your variables set to `public` within your Mailable class. By default, PHPStorm will make your properties `private` and they won't be accessible within the email blade template.