# I want to send email using improved laravel email, I want to send some variable along with view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This is my mail class

```
class createassets extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('email.createassets');
}
}
```

this is function where i am calling this mail class to send email but i want to send some variable on view. I am using the below method but getting undefined variable error

```
$responsibleperson=employees::where('id',Input::get('rid'))->first();
                Mail::to($responsibleperson->email)->send(new createassets)->with([
                    'username' => $responsibleperson->name,
                    'inventoryno' => $lastid,
                     'creator'=>Auth::user()->name
                ]);;
```

I want to show **username** **creator** and **inventoryno** on email view

Comment: have you tried my answer?

Comment: hello, if you tried our solution then please accept it and upvote it. if you have find your own solution then post it as an answer to close this question as per SO guidelines > https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$data = array( 'email' => 'sample@sample.com', 'first_name' => 'Lar', 'from' => 'sample@sample.comt', 'from_name' => 'Vel' );

Mail::send( 'email.welcome', $data, function( $message ) use ($data)
{
    $message->to( $data['email'] )->from( $data['from'], $data['first_name'])->subject( 'Welcome!' );
});
```

source:
http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/pass-variables-inside-the-mail-function

You can use variables directly in view

```
Name: {{$first_name}} 
Email: {{$email}}
```

Comment: I want to use improved structure, It is something i have to do with mail class

Comment: Also your question is duplicated with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412055/sending-email-with-laravel-but-doesnt-recognize-variable

Answer (score 0):

First of all use markdown files as Laravel 5.5 encourages us to use md files they are fast and easy to do formatting and also you can generate text mails using md files.

Read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail) for more

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class createassets extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $username;
    public $inventoryno;
    protected $creator;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($username,$inventoryno,$creator)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->inventoryno = $inventoryno;
        $this->creator = $creator;

    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
         return $this->markdown('emails.createassets')
                    ->with([
                        'username' => $this->username,
                        'inventoryno' => $this->inventoryno,
                        'creator' => $this->creator,
                    ]);
    }
}
```